# Problems streaming local flv file with CRTMP server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, streaming, rtmpd

Has anybody experienced problem with streaming locally saved flv trough CRTMP like the problem I have:

I get the buffer emptied and flushed 10-11 seconds before the real end of the file.

I get also "done streaming" message in crtmp log file 10-11 seconds before the real end of the file.

I cannot seek my file at the end because hte buffer is empty.

Does this happens because the flv file is not properly configured or it is due to some server error?

Comment: Can you please share the output of `crtmpserver --version`? FYI, latest trunk works just fine with JWPlayer. I will do a test with flowplayer and come back with the results. Also, my home-made player works as well

Comment: One more thing. "Done streaming" message on the crtmpserver side means the server is done sending all the data. The player now is responsible of playing back that data.